# Zoiper5 error executing process on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, client, sip

### 1st Error

Getting constantly error executing process message running Zoiper5.

Full error message from terminal given below:

```
[0702/132442.732827:ERROR:gl_implementation.cc(292)] Failed to load ~/Zoiper5/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: ~/Zoiper5/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[0702/132442.756816:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(197)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0702/132442.767416:ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(252)] Attempting to run unsupported native service: ~/Zoiper5/content_gpu.service
^CAPP Exit [ PID: 16409 ]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

### 2nd Error

Downloading another zip file of zoiper from searching google (Lost the file and site address) it started fine but after restarting PC when I try to start it only shows some blinking icon on sidebar for a couple time and stop.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong or need any information.

Comment: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` is a programming error.  As this is a product that is not open, best you contact the developers.

Comment: How can I contact developer when I'm using free version?

Comment: https://www.zoiper.com/en/contact

Comment: Try to select Private person and then FREE product. Already tried, no contact for free user. Only community is the solution.

Comment: Like I said: it's not an Ubuntu problem, so you won't find any answers here, sorry for your loss! (of rep)

Comment: :) Just hopped for any ubuntu user already faced or solved the issue. Thanks for your time here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the following error message (**1st Error**):

> Failed to load ~/Zoiper5/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: ~/Zoiper5/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

In Ubuntu 17.10 and later the libGLESv2.so.2 file is provided by the libgles2 package and it is installed at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2`. libgles2 can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 17.10 and later with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install libgles2
```

Create a symbolic link at `~/Zoiper5/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so` which references to file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2 ~/Zoiper5/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so
```

Check that you have the version of Zoiper5 installed the gave the 1st Error, so that you won't get an error message that the system can't find `~/Zoiper5/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so`.